# Firebase authentication token expiration with Next.js SSR

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Next.js app with Firebase authentication. I store the JWT in a cookie so that it can be accessed on the server side from `getServerSideProps`. However, since Firebase tokens expire every hour, if I leave the app open for more than an hour the token doesn't refresh automatically and if I go to refresh the page I cannot retrieve data because my token has expired and I get a `401` unauthorized.

I also can't refresh my token since `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken` is only available on the client side, and I can't reach client side because I am unauthorized. How can I refresh my token on the server side?

I tried `Firebase Admin` but the JWT has a different issuer and audience.

Comment: Auth tokens are only means to be used in client apps that are under the control of the user.  If you don't have a client app, then the user isn't really signed in at all.  Auth state isn't meant to be managed on the backend, just the client.

Comment: @DougStevenson Right, but I need to refresh the token on the back end so that I can do server side rendering to fetch data only authorized users can see.

Comment: The client is expected to refresh it's own token.  That's also not a function of the backend.  The client passes the token to the backend in order to authorize it to do work on the user's behalf, not to refresh it.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson I am facing the same dilemma. Assume I have two pages, home page and Dashboard. If the user is signed in I need them to redirect to dashboard directly and not show them the homepage at all. There is now way I can make this check serverside? Currently the homepage loads waits for the currently signed in user then redirects to dashboard. Which is a bit of bad UX

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any progress?